# Using CHARINDEX IN SQL SERVER TO SPLIT A STRING WITH MULTIPLE SPECIAL CHARACTERS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field called contract details with the following contents

- Money~25030.1!RATE~12!DAYS~30!YEAR~360!

I would like to split it as below

> Money   |     rate  |    days | year

> 25030.1 |     12    |     30  | 360

How can Archive this using CHARINDEX AND SUBSTRING

Sometimes the contains appear like below, with no days but the days column can be recalculated.

YEAR~360!RATE~16!Money~421777.78!

> year   |     rate  |    money

> 360    |     12    |    25030.1

Comment: is it always 4 `fields` in the same order ?

Comment: Have you tried solving this yourself, and, if so, can you include that code in the question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i have tried it, let me add the initial code i had tried.

Comment: @Squirrel sometimes it appears like this YEAR~360!RATE~16!Money~421777.78!, but i gues the days column can be recomputed from the dates in the table

Comment: what `dates`  in the table ? Can you show us all relevant information from the table ? And also all possible scenario ? You are wasting others time and effort that comes out a solution that would not work for your other scenario. Please update your question with these information and not in the comments.

Comment: Hi @Squirrel those are the two possible scenarios, and the Days column can be recomputed from contract end and start dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('Money', col) + 6,
                   CHARINDEX('!RATE~', col) - CHARINDEX('Money', col) - 6) AS Money,
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('!RATE~', col) + 6,
                   CHARINDEX('!DAYS~', col) - CHARINDEX('!RATE~', col) - 6) AS rate,
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('!DAYS~', col) + 6,
                   CHARINDEX('!YEAR~', col) - CHARINDEX('!DAYS~', col) - 6) AS days,
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('!YEAR~', col) + 6, LEN(col)),
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('!YEAR~', col) + 6,
                   CHARINDEX('!', SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('!YEAR~', col) + 6, LEN(col))) - 1) AS year
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that the above query, as the demo shows, is robust with regard to your target text appearing anywhere inside a larger string.

Comment: how about if the length of the string is changing over time, how can we make this dynamic

Comment: Got it , everywhere you placed a +6, instead of doing this , replace 6 with LEN('Money') _>> that is on the first line, , the first CHARACTER you are searching for